# Testers needed for my Surround Ambiances sampler instrument

Tags: sound-design, surround-sound, sampler, kontakt, ambiance

Hi there,

I am looking for some feedback from people who work within sound for picture for my Final Major Project on my MSc Sound Design course.

I have created a selection of surround sound ambiances within Kontakt 4 and have written a script to give the user full control over each sound included in the ambiance (position in 5.1, volume, pitch etc) and would love some comments on how successful (or not!) you think these work and how they could be improved.

The thread of my original project idea of a foley sample set is here [Foley sampler instrument - Some questions to sound designers](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/8993/foley-sampler-instrument-some-questions-to-sound-designers)

I changed the focus of this towards creating a tool for the quick creation of realistic surround environments in different situations. These are meant to be a better alternative than buying sample CDs of pre-mixed sounds and ambiances and a quicker alternative to traditional track-laying of sounds.

To test the surround sampler instruments you will need Kontakt 4 and, of course, a 5.1 monitor system.

If you are interested in giving me some comments for the evaluation part of my project, please email simonmakessound@gmail.com and I will send you a link to download the instruments and the instructions on how to use them.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: I've had some interest in this but could do with as many people as possible to give me feedback. It should only take you 1/2hr - 1hr to have a play with the instruments and write your comments :)

Thanks

Comment: I really need to get Kontakt 4... Kontakt 3.5 isn't getting any new toys, and it seems like people are finally developing decent libraries for sound design.

Answer (score 1):

Have retweeted @Surround2011 - they have many experts there, who may be able to help.
Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Is anyone else interested in this?

I have only a few days left to present my written work/critique and could do with a few more testers.

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I am interested. email sent.

Answer (score 0):

Only another couple of days left until I need the feedback - so if you're interested please send an email to simonmakessound@gmail.com

Thanks

Simon